# Applet Certificate CRL Distribution Point LDAP URL with no host

Tags: java, security, applet, ldap, certificate-revocation

I'm developing a web application that uses applets signed with a certificate issued by the customer CA. That certificate contains an URL to a CRL Distribution Point that does not define the host and port. The certificate attributes "CRL Distribution Points" and "Authority Information Access" contain an URL similar to "ldap:///CN=my-cn...".

The log files generated by the Certificate Revocation-Checking API (C:\Users[my_user]\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log) indicate that the values "localhost" and "389" are being used for host and port. This is a snippet of the log file:

```
...
certpath: DistributionPointFetcher.getCRLs: Checking CRLDPs for CN=xxx, O=yyy, L=zzz, C=PT
certpath: Trying to fetch CRL from DP ldap:///CN=_my-cn_?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint
certpath: CertStore URI:ldap:///CN=_my-cn_?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint
...
network: Connecting http://localhost:389/ with proxy=DIRECT
...
certpath: LDAPCertStore.engineInit about to throw InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 [Root exception is    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
...
```

Can anyone confirm that the host is mandatory, otherwise the default value "localhost" is used?

I read in the LDAP RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4516.txt) that if the "host" field is not present, the client must have some a priori knowledge of an appropriate LDAP server to contact. Is it possible to configure the "host" attribute?

I'm using the JRE version 1.7.0_45 (build 1.7.0_45-b18).

Thank you,
Telmo Simões

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the host is mandatory.

It depends a bit on how (if) your code creates the `LDAPCertStore` object. When you call the constructor, you need to pass an `LDAPCertStoreParameters` object to it. That class contains a contructor which allows you to specify the host (and port).

Try creating your `LDAPCertStore` like this:

```
LDAPCertStoreParameters params = new LDAPCertStoreParameters( "hostname", 389 );
CertStore   store = CertStore.getInstance("LDAP", params);
```

Good luck.